# Updating UsageTime in SQL Server via Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

[image]

I want to update the `UsageTime` when the time ticks per minute, couldn't get the right code.

```
Private Sub LBLTime_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LBLTime.TextChanged

    con.ConnectionString = My.Settings.Finals_DBConnectionString
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Close()
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "update tbl_transaction set usagetime = @ut, remainingtime = @rt"
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ut", +1)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rt", -1)
    cmd.Parameters cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: database in use ?

Comment: microsoft sql server management 2008

Comment: Was the event really triggered? Why you close the connection before using it? What does "couldn't get the right code" mean? Does this current code compilable?

Comment: i want to update my usagetime in mssql, whenever a minute pass by

Comment: I delete the connection close

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
update tbl_transaction set usagetime = usagetime+1 , remainingtime = remainingtime -1
```

Also don't see any "where"  in your sql. It's not a good practice

Comment: apparently, your code didn't work as intended, nothing happens. the idea behind the system  that the usage time will increase and decreasing the remaining time as the time pass.

Comment: use this query in ssis and see if its working  ? If its working , then its the problem of your execution

Comment: i don't have ssis :(

Comment: try from visual studio  or any other tool which you use to connect to sqlserver