# Visual Studio + SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I need help. I want to update my SQL Server where my table name = Usagetime.
When time tick every minute the value of usage time will increase by 1.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, store the start time & calculate the usage on demand.

Comment: my sql is connected to visual studio. i want to update the usage time when every minute pass by. "real time"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating UsageTime in SQL Server via Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441558/updating-usagetime-in-sql-server-via-visual-studio)

Comment: This appears to be just clarification for your previous thread. SO is not a code writing service. You need to add a timer to your application to do whatever it is you want to happen.